# Using the `content` attribute as an HTML Template

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to use the CSS `content` property to make somewhat of a "template" for an element of a specific class.

I've tried multiple things. . .

Many places I have seen told me to convert everything to hexadecimal, so I did, until I saw that using hex wrote the litteral characters into the element, instead of evaluating the characters as HTML.

I then tried just litterally entering the characters into the content, and I got the exact same result (this makes it appear as if there is no purpose for the hex, yet thats hard to belive with how many people say there is. . . ).

Is there any way that I can place HTML content into an element using the CSS content attribute?

[I've made a JS-Fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/zdht6rta/):

And, of course, Stack wants my source:

HTML:

```
<button id="normal" >Show with normal output</button>
<button id="hex" >Show with Hexadecimal output</button>
<div id="class_changer" ></div>
```

JS:

```
function changeClass(evt)
{
    class_changer.className = evt.srcElement.id;
}
var class_changer = document.getElementById('class_changer');
var normal = document.getElementById('normal').addEventListener('click', changeClass, true);
var hex = document.getElementById('hex').addEventListener('click', changeClass, true);
```

And the un-godly long CSS:

```
.normal::before {
    content: '<a href="http://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/facebook/offer?pco=tbx32nj-1.0&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cimtrak.com&amp;username=cimcor" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" src="http://cache.addthis.com/icons/v1/thumbs/32x32/facebook.png" /></a>';
}

.hex::before {
    content: '\0027\003c\0061\0020\0068\0072\0065\0066\003D\0022\0068\0074\0074\0070\003A\002F\002F\0061\0070\0069\002E\0061\0064\0064\0074\0068\0069\0073\002E\0063\006F\006D\002F\006F\0065\0078\0063\0068\0061\006E\0067\0065\002F\0030\002E\0038\002F\0066\006F\0072\0077\0061\0072\0064\002F\0066\0061\0063\0065\0062\006F\006F\006B\002F\006F\0066\0066\0065\0072\003F\0070\0063\006F\003D\0074\0062\0078\0033\0032\006E\006A\002D\0031\002E\0030\0026\0061\006D\0070\003B\0075\0072\006C\003D\0068\0074\0074\0070\0025\0033\0041\0025\0032\0046\0025\0032\0046\0077\0077\0077\002E\0063\0069\006D\0074\0072\0061\006B\002E\0063\006F\006D\0026\0061\006D\0070\003B\0075\0073\0065\0072\006E\0061\006D\0065\003D\0063\0069\006D\0063\006F\0072\0022\0020\0074\0061\0072\0067\0065\0074\003D\0022\005F\0062\006C\0061\006E\006B\0022\003e\003c\0069\006D\0067\0020\0061\006C\0074\003D\0022\0046\0061\0063\0065\0062\006F\006F\006B\0022\0020\0073\0072\0063\003D\0022\0068\0074\0074\0070\003A\002F\002F\0063\0061\0063\0068\0065\002E\0061\0064\0064\0074\0068\0069\0073\002E\0063\006F\006D\002F\0069\0063\006F\006E\0073\002F\0076\0031\002F\0074\0068\0075\006D\0062\0073\002F\0033\0032\0078\0033\0032\002F\0066\0061\0063\0065\0062\006F\006F\006B\002E\0070\006E\0067\0022\0020\002F\003e\003c\002F\0061\003e';
}
```

Check it out at JS-Fiddle and see what you can do! Let me know! Thanks everybody!

**UPDATE: SOLVED (ish...)**

Yes, wierd question sometimes accept wierd answers (like iterating over the DOM...) but if you have a better solution, I'm all ears.

As it turns out, the accepted answers means of evaluating a "CSS template" may be the best means of performing "templating" without the use of third-party libraries or the new `<template>` tag (that I'm still not sure of) even though it makes my skin crawl (if anyone has a better solution, please post it). Either way, [I've updated my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/zdht6rta/1/), so check it out!

Although, I guess the best answer would be purely making a template as a string in JavaScript, that is, if we are going to be evaluating it later on and pre-pending it to an element. Yea, that would make more sense...

Comment: Can I just ask, why would you extort that level of abstraction? Should you not be keeping the CSS to styling and templates for, well... templates?

Comment: Very true @JamesMartin-Davies, but the curiosity has gotten a hold of me...

Comment: Btw @JamesMartin-Davies, I am all ears to another approach of templating, that is, if there are no third party libraries or frameworks involved (including JQuery). I know how to do templating with third party stuff, but I actually don't know how to do any without it. If you know of a way, please let me know. It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible with plain CSS. However, if you really want to save these templates in CSS, you could iterate over all elements and use

```
window.getComputedStyle(element, ':before').content
```

to fetch the content and then prepend/append it to the element. To parse the HTML, you could either use jQuery.parseHTML, new DOMParser().parseFromString or a dummy DOM element. Alternatively, you could also use .innerHTML directly, but I wouldn't recommend that..